# c# Generic List

Tags: c#, .net, generics, list, methods

I m populating data for different entities into set of lists using generic lists as follows :

```
List<Foo> foos ..
List<Bar> bars ..
```

I need to write these lists to a file, i do have a util method to get the values of properties etc. using reflection.

What i want to do is: using a single method to write these into files such as:

```
 void writeToFile(a generic list)
 {
  //Which i will write to file here.
 }
```

How can i do this?

I want to be able to call :

```
writeToFile(bars);
writeToFile(foos);
```

Comment: It is really good to make a generic method like all the answers do. But I want to mention that since 2012, there are _covariant_ interfaces such as [`IReadOnlyList<out T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1). Here "`out`" means the interface is **covariant** in `T`. So if you make a method `WriteToFile(IReadOnlyList<object> list) { /* ... */ }` then it will allow both a `List<Foo>` and a `List<Bar>` as long as `Foo` and `Bar` are _reference types_. Of course, you could use `IReadOnlyList<IYourWritable> list` or similar also.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void writeToFile<T>(List<T> list)
{
    // Do the writing
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use generics to allow the caller to specify the expected type the list contains.

```
void writeToFile<T>(IList<T> list)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm thats what you get for loading a question and not replying for a while - Jacob got there first.

Answer (score 3):

Probably something like...

```
private void WriteToFile<T>(
  IEnumerable<T> elementsToWrite,
  Func<T, string> convertElementToString) {
  foreach (var element in elementsToWrite)
  {
    var stringRepresentation = convertElementToString(element);
    // do whatever other list-stuff you need to do
  }
}

// called like so...
WriteToFile(listOfFoo, foo => foo.FP1 + ", " + foo.FP2 + " = " foo.FP3);
WriteToFile(listOfBar, bar => bar.BP1 +"/"+ bar.BP2 + "[@x='" + bar.BP3 + "']");
```

...or you could try something like...

```
private void WriteToFile<T>(
  IEnumerable<T> elementsToWrite,
  Action<T, TextWriter> writeElement) {
  var writer = ...;

  foreach (var element in elementsToWrite)
  {
    // do whatever you do before you write an element
    writeElement(element, writer);
    // do whatever you do after you write an element
  }
}

// called like so...
WriteToFile(listOfFoo, (foo, writer) =>
  writer.Write("{0}, {1} = {2}", foo.FP1, foo.FP2, foo.FP3));
WriteToFile(listOfBar, (bar, writer) =>
  writer.Write("{0}/{1}[@x='{2}']", bar.BP1, bar.BP2, bar.BP3));
```

...or whatever... you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the topic of [serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c%23%20serialization). There is are [some](https://web.archive.org/web/20200204000600/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/07/20/114076.aspx) [articles](https://web.archive.org/web/20100727034820/http://shiman.wordpress.com:80/2008/07/24/serialization-for-generic-type-in-c-net/) out there about dealing with generic types.